# what does -> implies in here in this perl code?

Tags: perl, hashmap

```
open PROPS, $propertyFile or die "Cannot open $propertyFile";
while ( my $lines = <PROPS> ) {
    chop $line;
    my @fields = split(/,/, $line)
    $r_CntrProp->{$fields[0]}->{$fields[1]} = {
        'behaviour'  => $fields[2],
        'type'       => $fields[3],
        'compressed' => $fields[4]
    };
}
```

propertyFile is being read as input file from user.

Comment: Where in that code is `-->` ? I only see `->`, which is used to access the stuff that a reference points to. Please [edit] your question and either correct the title or paste the code that contains `-->`.

Comment: @Corion i rectified my mistake

Comment: Check references, https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: `-->` [is the "goes to" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c)

Comment: http://perlmonks.org?node=References+quick+reference

Comment: `EXPR1->{EXPR2}` is a hash element dereference. It gets the element with key `EXPR2` from the hash referenced by `EXPR1`.

Answer (score 3):

> `$r_CntrProp->{$fields[0]}->{$fields[1]}`

In this piece of code, for each arrow (`->`) :

- the left side is a hash reference
- the right side, enclosed between `{}`, is a hash key

The expression gives access to whatever is stored under the key within the hash reference. Your code actually assigns something to that hash entry (a hash reference).

See [The Arrow Operator in `perlop`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator) and [Using References in `perlref`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References).

Basically, `$r_CntrProp` is *a reference to a hash of hash references*, like :

```
my $r_CntrProp  = {
    foo => {
        bar => 'baz'
    }
};

print $r_CntrProp->{foo}->{bar}, "\n";
```

Yields :

```
baz
```